# Pass a save confirmation message across actions in an MVC application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display a "Save Successful" message at the top of my form on Save.  The issue I have is that when I save it is doing a POST/Redirect/GET so the action I'm saving in isn't the action I am returning a view from.

I have attempted to use ViewData in the POST action but due to the redirect it is across requests so by the time it's at the GET the ViewData dictionary is cleared.

Any ideas on the best way to pass the confirmation message and store it so it is easily accessible in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the TempData dictionary whenever the PRG pattern is applied. For example you could do this:

Controller:

```
TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Save Successful";
```

View:

```
@if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["SuccessMessage"]))
{
  <div class="success">
    <p> @TempData["SuccessMessage"] </p>
  </div>
}
```

The best way to use this accross the entire application would be writing a partial view. Then you would only need to call the partial view in your layout and set the messages in your actions.

Check these answers, there might be useful:

- [ASP.NET MVC - TempData - Good or bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386681/asp-net-mvc-tempdata-good-or-bad-practice/565653#565653)
- [Difference Between ViewData and TempData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173159/difference-between-viewdata-and-tempdata/173650#173650)

Comment: Good idea using TempData, however I dislike the idea of your partial view, especially since you are doing 'if' logic in your view.  Instead I created a HtmlHelper called DisplayConfirmation() to do the work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you either do some sort of C# logic in Views or you do HTML generation in a helper which is another side of the same coin

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/adding-rails-like-flash-message-in-asp-dot-net-mvc

Maybe you will find some other some useful utilities

Answer (score 1):

I use strongly-typed views, and try to avoid passing any information through TempData or ViewBag whenever possible.

So, I would add a string to my view model containing the message, as well as whatever flags are needed to indicate to the View whether that message should be displayed or not.

You didn't provide any sample code for your Action, your View, or your Model, so I don't have any to edit as an example. Here's some vague barebones code instead:

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel {
    // Whatever things you would normally have in your view model here
    ...

    public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }
    public bool ShowSuccessMessage { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
public ActionResult HandleTheForm( ViewModel theModel ) {
    var newModel = new ViewModel();

    //Do whatever stuff you need to do to process the form
    ...

    newModel.SuccessMessage = "The operation succeeded.";
    newModel.ShowSuccessMessage = true;

    return View( newModel );
}
```

**View**

```
@model ViewModel

@if( Model.ShowSuccessMessage ) {
    <span class="success">@Model.SuccessMessage</span><br />
}
```