# pass data from Action To Another Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How would you pass the model from an (GetDate) action to another (ProcessP) action via RedirectAction method?

Here's the source code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDate(FormCollection values, DateParameter newDateParameter)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
return RedirectToAction("ProcessP");
    }
    else
    {
return View(newDateParameter);
    }
}


public ActionResult ProcessP()
{
   //Access the model from GetDate here??
    var model = (from p in _db.blah
 orderby p.CreateDate descending
 select p).Take(10);

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to pass data from one action to another one option is to utilize [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx). For example within GetDate you could add data to the session as follows:

```
TempData["Key"] = YourData
```

And then perform the redirect. Within ProcessP you can access the data utilizing the key you previously used:

```
var whatever = TempData["Key"];
```

For a decent read, I would recommend reading through this thread: [ASP.NET MVC - TempData - Good or bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386681/asp-net-mvc-tempdata-good-or-bad-practice)

Comment: ok; I will read it. So, can TempData hold a model? or is it like ViewData where it can only hold value pair? Thanks!

Comment: yes tempdata can hold your model, or whatever object you feel like placing within.

Comment: Just remember you have to cast it to the type inside TempData. Such as var model = (MyViewModel)TempData["Key"];