# Pass an object in RedirectToAction() using T4MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass data from Action To Another Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957501/pass-data-from-action-to-another-action)

I have a view in which I submit a form and depending on the results I want to redirect to an action. The view that correspondes to and action is strongly-typed and it should accept a ResultsViewModel.

I'm trying to pass the ResultsViewModel using T4MVC.

Below is the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult AddEntity(string viewModel)
    {
        //Deserialize using Json.NET
        var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEntity>(viewModel);

        var success = DoSomething(); //returns boolean
        if(success)
        {
            var result = new ResultsViewModel { MyEntity = entity, MessageId = 1};
            return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.ResultsPage(result));
        }

        var result = new ResultsViewModel { MyEntity = entity, MessageId = 2};
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.ResultsPage(result));
    }

    public virtual ActionResult ResultsPage(ResultsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

When the code reaches

```
    public virtual ActionResult ResultsPage(ResultsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

viewModel is always equal to null.

I know I can do something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ResultsPage", new { viewModel = result });
```

EDIT: I tried the return RedirectToAction("ResultsPage", new { viewModel = result }); and I'm also getting a null in my viewModel.

However I'm trying to figure out why/how to pass an object using T4MVC.

Thanks,

Comment: Fire up fiddler and see what the redirect url looks like. I bet that MyEntiy looks nothing like what default binder can chew. Btw, you second option is also unlikely to work if the first one does not. Can you confirm if you really tested it and it works, or you *think* it *might* work?

Comment: @zespri Thanks, I fired up fiddler and found the error. Basically I can't pass an object like that unless I do something like Gabe suggests. There's a related post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TempData`

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult AddEntity(string viewModel)
{
    //Deserialize using Json.NET
    var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEntity>(viewModel);

    var success = DoSomething(); //returns boolean
    if(success)
    {
        var result = new ResultsViewModel { MyEntity = entity, MessageId = 1};
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.ResultsPage(result));
    }

    var result = new ResultsViewModel { MyEntity = entity, MessageId = 2};

    TempData["Result"] = result;


    return RedirectToAction(MVC.MyController.ResultsPage(result));
}

public virtual ActionResult ResultsPage()
{
    ResultsViewModel model = (ResultsViewModel)TempData["Result"];
    return View(model);
}
```