# MVC4 passing messages from one controller to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Imagine I have one controller that register somebody and if successful should display a message on another controller view.

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
   {
       string msg = db.Register(model) 

       // Assuming msg contains "You have been succesfully registered" 
       // How do I display that on the Dashboard view??

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
   }
```

What's the best way to **pass a message** or a series of messages to the Dashboard controller??
Even better if I can pass a list of **objects with their own properties** (something like obj.Status && obj.Message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata) property. This will keep the data for 1 request so you will be able to access this on a Redirect.

```
TempData["MyObject"] = new MyObj
{
    prop1 = "Test",
    prop2 = "Prop"
}
```

You can then access it like:

```
var myObj = TempData["MyObject"] as MyObj;
```

OR

```
var myObj = (MyObj)TempData["MyObject"];
```

You can also make an extension method:

```
public MyObj GetMyObj(this TempDataDictionary tmpData)
{
    return (MyObj)tmpData["MyObject"];
}
```

Then access it this way:

```
var myObj = TempData.GetMyObj();
```

Comment: OK, I thought TempData was between the current controller and the related view only. Good to know ....

Answer (score 1):

They recomend to use TempData dictionary for this purpose.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
   string msg = db.Register(model) 

   TempData["Message"] = "You are registered!";

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

TempData can be used as ViewData, but internaly it lives in Session, and MVC itself takes care about cleaning it up after single redirect.

Only thing is - if you use web farm (more than one web server), you will need to configure your sessions properly to use the same storage (usually database)

There are also discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386681/asp-net-mvc-tempdata-good-or-bad-practice)